# Buddhist view on Aspergers

Tags: psychology, defilements, experiential

Clearly Asperger's/Autism is not something that exists independently on its own as an entity, but it is made up of component simple experiential phenomena.  What is such a view on Asperger's? What are its building components? What is it at the most fundamental level, as seen from Buddhist persepective?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The internet includes the following statements about Asperger's syndrome:

1. [Asperger’s syndrome](https://www.healthline.com/health/asperger-syndrome) belongs to a group of neurodevelopment conditions known as autism spectrum disorder.
2. It is not clear [what causes Asperger’s syndrome](https://www.healthdirect.gov.au/aspergers-syndrome#causes). It’s likely that genes and the environment play a part. It is not caused by upbringing or social circumstances.

As Asperger's syndrome is a neurodevelopment/genetic condition, it comes under the Buddha's teaching about 'the elements' ('[dhatu](https://suttacentral.net/define/dh%C4%81tu?lang=en)'). The Buddha explained (in [MN 12](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.012.ntbb.html) and [SN 14.15](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)) the different 'dispositions' ([adhimutti](https://suttacentral.net/define/adhimutti?lang=en)) of individual persons are determined by 'the elements'. In other words, Asperger's syndrome is not a 'defilement' ('[kilesa](https://suttacentral.net/define/kilesa?lang=en)').

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, it's a diagnosis and therefore a "name".

I think it's a name for a type of behaviour -- but "behaviour" maybe isn't a "fundamental building component as seen from Buddhist perspective" -- behaviour is a result, of other more fundamental causes.

I don't know but I think I read that a cause a "autism" is a difference in sense-perception.

- See for example here from autism.co.uk -- [Sensory differences](https://www.autism.org.uk/advice-and-guidance/topics/sensory-differences/sensory-differences/all-audiences)

  > Processing everyday sensory information can be difficult for autistic people. Any of their senses may be over- or under-sensitive, or both, at different times. These sensory differences can affect how they feel and act, and can have a profound effect on a person’s life. Here we help you to understand autism, the person and how to help.
- Although this doesn't seem to be mentioned on other introductory pages like the Mayo Clinic's -- [Autism spectrum disorder](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/autism-spectrum-disorder/symptoms-causes/syc-20352928)

In any case I think that "sense perception" probably would be considered a "fundamental building component" from the Buddhist perspective -- see e.g. the description of [phassa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spar%C5%9Ba) on Wikipedia.

As for Asperger's, I don't know -- my uninformed guess is:

- It's not the same sensory disorder as Autism (though a person might like quiet)
- When it's a "disorder" -- i.e. disfunction which comes to the attention of a psychiatrist -- it may sometimes have symptoms like autism, e.g. unusual social behaviour
- Psychiatry therefore classifies them -- by symptom -- together, as "autism spectrum"
- In general psychiatry describes symptoms but doesn't really understand causes -- in this way it's currently like medieval or "dark ages" medical science -- though it can recommend some sometimes-successful treatments

The autism spectrum very broad -- some people might be "high-functioning" -- so the question isn't very precise. I recently heard someone joke that you're "on the spectrum" if you know what "a trillion" is!

Comment: Thanks. What I should have elaborated is that I I wanted to understand a particular aspect of Asperger - social aspect. These individuals have "non normal" understanding of social rules etc. Ex. Sarcasm is mostly not understood, they are low on humour, have a hard time understanding what the other person may be feeling etc. 

My own suspect is that this suspect at least is not an inherent thing like let's say someone being blind or like skin color. What do you think about that?

Comment: Isn't it right to say that Buddhism sees little if anything as inherent in one thing? So-called social skills are a result of or dependent on a social situation/aggregate -- for example, you might feel awkward with some people but not others, depending on them and on their behaviour. Plus I suppose social behaviour in general is learned and nothing you're born with, learning itself being dependent on the environment/interactions as well as on some neurological capacity. Further, even "blindness" could be described as "dependent" -- on contact between light and the eye.

Comment: Really though I suppose I think it's just a name, a label. What I don't know is whether and how the label is useful to you. I suppose that's my usual standard for words -- is a Physics word like "gravity" or "friction" helpful in this situation, is it a good model -- is it informative of what's happening, or is it misleading, does it help you to behave skilfully? Because that's the extent to which -- and the occasions on which -- the word is worthwhile, like a knowledge of Physics for example is useful-occaionally -- it arises sometimes, impermanently.

Comment: I admire Buddhism for being more-generally useful/applicable -- it's doctrine of morality is more relevant to everyday social behaviour than, for example, the doctrine of Physics is.

Comment: I also think people can suffer as a result of being labelled. If you say to a child "You're a bad boy!" then they go around thinking, "Oh no, I'm a 'bad boy', and there's nothing I can do about it." So you need to be careful with labels: use them kindly; use them only to the extent that they're useful; and maybe (in the context of this example) use them to label a child's (transient) behaviour not their (more permanent or 'inherent') person, e.g. "That was unskillful behaviour" not "You're a bad boy".